# quarkus gradle test not executed

Tags: gradle, quarkus

I'am trying the quarkus getting-started project. With maven the contained unittest is executed. Then I tried the proposed gradle build file, because we use gradle instead of maven. When I run `gradle test`, the unittest is definitivly not executed (I know, because I modified it to fail).

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.quarkus.gradle.plugin' 

buildscript {     
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      //this is temporary, all dependencies should be in central soon
      url 'http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public'
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.quarkus:quarkus-gradle-plugin:0.11.0'
  }
}

repositories { 
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url 'http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public'
  }
}

dependencies { 
  compileOnly group: 'io.quarkus', name: 'quarkus-resteasy', version:'0.11.0'
  testCompile group: 'io.quarkus', name: 'quarkus-junit5', version:'0.11.0'
  testCompile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '3.3.0'
}
```

Is this a bug or do I anything wrong?

Comment: Hi @BananaJoe! Do you have some reproducing project I can try?

Comment: It is the sample quarkus project: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/archive/master.zip. Unzip and just paste the build file above in the folder getting-started. Use gradle 5.2 and call gradle test on the command line in the getting-started folder

Comment: Thanks! I will get back to you by tomorrow :)

Comment: This looks like a bug, would you like to open a issue on Quarkus github?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found the problem. Gradle does not use JUnit5 out of the box. You have to add the following to the build.gradle to get gradle starting the tests:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```